# webp fallback for img tag in html

Tags: html, webp

I know the solution is  `<picture>`

but which format is standard?

**1.**

```
 <picture>
   <source type="image/webp" srcset="pic.webp">
   <img src="pic.jpg"  alt="test">
 </picture>
```

**2.**

```
 <picture>
   <source type="image/webp" srcset="pic.webp">
   <img src="pic.jpg"  alt="test" type="image/jpeg">
 </picture>
```

**3.**

```
 <picture>
   <source type="image/webp" srcset="pic.webp">
   <source type="image/jpeg" srcset="pic.jpg">
   <img src="pic.jpg"  alt="test">
 </picture>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Number 1** would be the standard way of doing it.

When using the `<picture>` element the browser looks through each `<source>` element – starting from the top – to find an image that best fits the the current scenario. In your case it would only be if it supports the format in the `type` attribute. But it could also look for things like media queries in the `media` attribute or the pixel density of the user's screen if you add 2x or 3x versions in the `srcset` list.

As stated on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture), if the browser can't find a fitting match in the `<source>`s, it defaults to the `<img>` tag:

> The `<img>` element serves two purposes:
>
> It describes the size and other attributes of the image and its
> presentation. It provides a fallback in case none of the offered
> `<source>` elements are able to provide a usable image.

So the JPEG in your example doesn't need to have a `<source>` as well, because it will be chosen if none of the `<source>`s are used.