# Javascript Unerror method using another js file

Tags: javascript, html

`<img src="images/business-card.webp" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='images/business-card.jpg' " class="m-auto img-fluid">`

I want to write this feature from within js file. How can i do it ?

Comment: There are no doubt better ways to achieve image fallback for webp. FOr example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65529016/webp-fallback-for-img-tag-in-html). If you can avoid writing code, your application will be more reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create the image in javascript:

```
var image = document.createElement("IMG");
document.body.appendChild(image);
image.src = "images/business-card.webp;
image.class = "m-auto img-fluid";
```

Now, add an onerror function:

```
blah.onerror = function(){this.onerror=null; this.src='images/business-card.jpg'};
```